# Extend word embedding layer for incremental word2vec training with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word2vec

I'd like to train word vectors/embeddings incrementally. With each incremental run I want to extend the vocabulary of the model and add new rows to the embeddings matrix.

The embeddings matrix is a partitioned variable, so ideally I want to avoid using `assign` since it's not implemented for partitioned variables.

One way I tried, looks like this:

```
        # Set prev_vocab_size and new_vocab_size 
        #accordingly to the corpus/text of the current run

        prev_embeddings = tf.get_variable(
            'prev_embeddings',
            shape=[prev_vocab_size, FLAGS.embedding_size],
            dtype=tf.float32,
            initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0)
        )

        new_embeddings = tf.get_variable(
            'new_embeddings',
            shape=[new_vocab_to_add,
                   FLAGS.embedding_size],
            dtype=tf.float32,
            initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(
                -1.0, 1.0)
        )

        combined_embeddings = tf.concat(
            [prev_embeddings, new_embeddings], 0)

        embeddings = tf.Variable(
            combined_embeddings,
            expected_shape=[prev_vocab_size + new_vocab_to_add, FLAGS.embedding_size],
            dtype=tf.float32,
            name='embeddings')
```

Now, this works well for the first run. But if I do the second run, I get a `Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match` error because the restored original `prev_embeddings` variable (from the first run) doesn't match the new shape (based on the extended vocab) I declare in the second run.

So I modified the tf.train.Saver to save the `new_embeddings` as the `prev_embeddings` like this:

`saver = tf.train.Saver({"prev_embeddings": new_embeddings})`

Now, in the second run, the `prev_embeddings` has the shape of `new_embeddings` in the previous run and I don't get an error for this.

However, now the `new_embeddings` in the second run has a different shape than in the first run and therefore when restoring the variables from the first run, I get another `Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match` error.

What's the best way to extend/expand the embeddings variable incrementally with new vectors for new words in the vocabulary while keeping the old and trained vectors?

Any help would be much appreciated.